# SecVerifyTransformCreate memory leak?

Tags: c++, macos, memory-leaks

Take following code:

```
// init
CFDataRef signature = CFDataCreate(...);
CFDataRef pubKeyData = CFDataCreate(...);

CFArrayRef array = NULL;
OSStatus res = SecItemImport(pubKeyData, ..., &array);
SecKeyRef pubKey = (SecKeyRef) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(array, 0);

// everything goes wrong here
SecTransformRef verifier = SecVerifyTransformCreate(pubKey, signature, NULL);

// release
CFRelease(signature);
CFRelease(pubKeyData);
CFRelease(signature);
CFRelease(verifier);
```

In short: I'm importing public key and signature from file, creating verifier for that signature. On succeeding lines of code, I'm able to successfully validate the signature.

What I'm concerned about is memory leak which occurs when calling **SecVerifyTransformCreate** method. If I comment out that line, the leak is gone.

I've read all about *create rules* and *get rules* and I think I've got the releases figured out.

Comment: How have you established that there is a memory leak? Is it just that the memory usage of the application goes up, or are you gathering this through instrumentation?

Comment: The memory usage of application goes up. I've ran this piece of code in loop to test. I've also checked with Xcode's profiler (Leaks to be more specific) which showed there indeed is a 320 byte leak per each iteration. When the line is commented out, memory usage remains unchanged.

Comment: You need to be wary of memory usage as reported by the OS. Memory allocators will often hang on to released memory for eventual reuse, so an increase in that metric does not necessarily mean a leak. That being said, if the profiler reports a leak, then it is indeed concerning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some extensive testing, this is what I've found out:

As mentioned in question, on lines following code above, I'm executing verifier to check whether the signature is correct, the important method is:

```
CFTypeRef result = SecTransformExecute(verifier, NULL);
```

If I don't include this line of code, there is a 320B leak (per call) observable in Xcode's *Instrumentation* tool.

I suppose that method *SecVerifyTransformCreate* allocates some piece of memory and expects you to call *SecTransformExecute*, which then releases it. If you don't, there is a leak. IMO that's wrong behavior.

As Frank mentioned, memory usage as reported by OS grows even without an observable leak, but does not grow exponentially (it stopped at around 40MB in my case). That's correct behavior.

Kudos to Frank for elaboration.